# Raspberrypi ssh is not working

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Even with the ssh enabled, I cannot connect my Windows 10 machine to the pi. When I try to login with PuTTY, it says "Access Denied". Any ways to fix this?

Comment: This question may be better suited for [super user](http://superuser.com/) instead as it's not a programming related question

Comment: "Access denied" sounds like a pure windows error, so the problem is likely at the client end. Can you connect to any other server with putty from the same machine? Can you connect to your pi from some other machine?